# に or で in the sentence pattern "ニュース(に/で)、...という報道があった"

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-で

I made the following sentence:

> テレビ東京は、政治に関するニュース**に**、（中略）という報道があった

However, a Japanese friend of mine advised that I should replace the particle に with で.

I googled and found a similar sentence, and indeed で is used instead of に.

> テレビのニュース速報**で**「マグニチュード5、○○市の震度は3でした。」という報道があった。

In my understanding, で expresses the place an action happens and に expresses the place a static object is laid at, shown in the following examples.

> 天安門広場｛**に**／ *で｝自由の**女神像**があった。
>   天安門広場｛*に／**で**｝大規模な**騒乱**があった。

However, 報道 doesn't seem to be an "action." Could someone help me figure out the reason why で is better than に in the sentence structure "ニュースで、...という報道があった"?

Comment: I think 報道 is an action, which is to report news.

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam May I ask which one would you choose? 昨日の朝日新聞(に/で)、（～）という報道があった.

Comment: I say 昨日の朝日新聞に、～という記事があった. 記事 is an object, not an action. 報道 is usually used for broadcasting.

Comment: Thank you. I'll memorize "新聞に、～という記事があった" and "ニュースで、～という報道があった" as a set.